# Sending headers in mjpeg img src

Tags: javascript, stream, xmlhttprequest, fetch, mjpeg

I would like to send credentials HTTP headers in my mjpeg URL in `src` attribute of `img`.
As it is not possible directly, I'm looking for a way to show the mjpeg stream in my react app.

**First try : Using fetch API**

```
mjpeg(cameraId, cb) {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    const signal = abortController.signal;
    fetch(this.endpoint + "camera/get/mjpeg/" + cameraId + "/", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: this.getHeaders(),
        mode: "cors",
        redirect: "follow",
        signal
    }).then((response) => {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        let imageBuffer = [];
        const stream = new ReadableStream({
            start(controller) {
                // The following function handles each data chunk
                const push = () => {
                    // "done" is a Boolean and value a "Uint8Array"
                    return reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
                        let i = 0;
                        while (i < value.length) {
                            if (i < (value.length - 2)) {
                                    // New image
                                    if (value[i] === 255 && value[i+1] === 216) {
                                        // console.log("jpeg found !");
                                        imageBuffer = [];
                                    }
                                    // End image
                                    if (value[i] === 255 && value[i+1] === 217) {
                                        // console.log("jpeg end !" + i + " / " + value.length);
                                        imageBuffer.push(value[i]);
                                        imageBuffer.push(value[i + 1]);

                                        const _arrayBufferToBase64 = (buffer) => {
                                            var binary = '';
                                            var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
                                            var len = bytes.byteLength;
                                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                                binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
                                            }
                                            return window.btoa( binary );
                                        };

                                        cb(null, false, _arrayBufferToBase64(imageBuffer));

                                        imageBuffer = [];
                                        i++;
                                    } else {
                                        imageBuffer.push(value[i]);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    imageBuffer.push(value[i]);
                                }
                                i++;
                            }

                            // Protect buffer
                            if (imageBuffer.length > 4000000) {
                                imageBuffer = [];
                            }

                            // Is there no more data to read?
                            if (done) {
                                // Tell the browser that we have finished sending data
                                cb(null, true);
                                return;
                            }

                            // Get the data and send it to the browser via the controller

                            if (abortController.signal.aborted) {
                                throw Error("Stream aborted");
                            } else {
                                try {
                                    controller.enqueue(value);
                                } catch(e) {

                                }
                            }

                        }).then(push);
                    };

                    push();
            }
        });

        const abort = () => {
            stream.cancel();
            abortController.abort();
        };

        cb(null, false, null, abort);

        return new Response(stream, { headers: { "Content-Type": "image/jpeg" } });
    }).catch((error) => {
        cb(error, true);
    });
}
```

With this code, I can successfully display the image in a container, can stop the stream (not cleanly - throw an exception). **It works as expected, but only on Chrome**, not Safari or Firefox.

**Second try : Using XMLHttpRequest**

I would like to do the same process with XMLHttpRequest. So I can add headers manually and decrypt stream during transfer.

But I have those issues :
Stream seems to work only with `responseText`, not `response`.
I can't convert correctly `responseText` to `Uint8Array`

**I would like a solution for the fetch API with stream readers which does not work at all under firefox / safari.**

Any ideas ?

Comment: this is unreadable, it will take more time for us to make it readable than to try to fix your code, so I'd suggest you refactor it and make it less v-nested and more modularized and human-friendly thus increasing chances of your question to be even considered.

Comment: Did you read the post ? Guess you don't. Code is a prototype and secondary. The question was - how to stream binary data with XMLHttpRequest. - Found a workaround by myself.

Comment: 1. Apologies for that seemingly cutting tone in the comment, it was not supposed to be aggresive. 2. As of question, of course I did, and other 114 people did in this 10 day period. It's not about  secondary or primary, it's just too much cognitive load per small visual area. Code is meant to better the context of question, make it easier to get in, since textual description that for you is clear may be pretty vague for others. 3. if you found a solution, it'd be great to post it as an answer, so community can benefit from it.

Comment: You're welcome. Instead of using headers authentication for mjpeg stream, I do it in 2 times. First, request an authentication token on the backend. This token will be usable1 time only, and can be passed through url or GET parameter. Next, called the mjpeg stream URL with the token inside. Then on server side, reject the used token to avoid man in the middle attacks. All communications are SSL encrypted, so the headers credentials for token retrieval should not be accessible.